# I can't get a value from one of two feeders

Tags: scala, gatling

I have two feeders in my test scenario

When i use one of them in first request it works alright, however when I use it in the next request block it doesn't work

I have tried changing the `feed(feederName)` position but still having the same problem

Here is a snippet of my test scenario with some comment to explain what's not working

```scala
//the Two feeders
  val kmPerYearFeeder = Iterator.continually(
    Map("kmPerYear" -> Random.shuffle(List("10000", "15000", "20000", "25000", "30000", "35000", "40000", "45000", "50000")).head)
  )
  val customerTypes = Iterator.continually(
    Map("customerType" -> Random.shuffle(List("P","B")).head)
  )

//here the customerTypes feeder is working
val homepage = feed(customerTypes)
    .exec(http("homepage")
    .get("/?customer_type=${customerType}"))

//this block is not really important but working alright 
  val pdp = exec(http("homepage")
     ....
// the feeder here doesn't work
  val calculate_rate  = feed(kmPerYearFeeder)
.exec(http("calculate_random_rate")
    .get(session => session("random_pdp_link").as[String] + "?inquiry_type=&km_per_year=${kmPerYear}")
    .check(status.is(200)))

  val pdp_scenario = scenario("PDP").exec(homepage).exec(pdp).exec(calculate_rate)

  setUp(
    pdp_scenario.inject(
      rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds),
    ).protocols(httpProtocol),
)
```

these are the get requests that are executed (got them from the logger)

```
GET ********?inquiry_type=&km_per_year=$%7BkmPerYear%7D
GET ********?inquiry_type=&km_per_year=$%7BkmPerYear%7D
GET ********?inquiry_type=&km_per_year=$%7BkmPerYear%7D
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in where you attempt to use the Gatling EL to reference the kmPerYear session var in

```
.get(session => session("random_pdp_link").as[String] + "?inquiry_type=&km_per_year=${kmPerYear}")
```

this version of .get takes a session function (which you are using to get "random_pdp_link"), but the Gatling EL doesn't work in session functions.

You either need to get it manually using 
`session("kmPerYear").as[String]`

or to reference "random_pdp_link" via the EL and not use the session function get. eg:
`.get("${random_pdp_link}?inquiry_type=&km_per_year=${kmPerYear}")`